# CMake: Compile unit test natively and cross compile code for embedded target

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, cmake, embedded, googletest

We are developing an application for an embedded MCU (stm32) and we are trying to set up unit testing with googletest. Is it possible to compile a target using the embedded compiler (gcc-arm-none and some compile options) and compile another target (the unit tests) using the native compiler with CMake? We would abstract and mock the hardware dependencies. This would allow us to run the tests on the host computer and during CI.

I am open to another approach if this is not the way to go or if this approach have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. For cross-compilation, you use a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling). When building tests, simply do not specify the toolchain file, to use the native toolchain.

You can also set a flag that indicates that tests are being built and use that inside `CmakeLists.txt`:

```cmake
if(ENABLE_TESTING)
    enable_testing()
    add_subdirectory(test)
else()
    # Build embedded app
endif()
```